# Get result of three related entities

Tags: php, symfony

I have three entities a user, a category and and event, a user can be intressted in many categories and an event can have a categorie.

User.php:

namespace Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

```
/**
 * Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $nom
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @var string $prenom
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $prenom;

/**
 * @var string $login
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="login", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $login;

/**
 * @var string $pass
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="pass", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $pass;

/**
 * @var Categorie
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Categorie", inversedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="interesse",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="User_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Categorie_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $categorie;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->categorie = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set nom
 *
 * @param string $nom
 */
public function setNom($nom)
{
    $this->nom = $nom;
}

/**
 * Get nom
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getNom()
{
    return $this->nom;
}

/**
 * Set prenom
 *
 * @param string $prenom
 */
public function setPrenom($prenom)
{
    $this->prenom = $prenom;
}

/**
 * Get prenom
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPrenom()
{
    return $this->prenom;
}

/**
 * Set login
 *
 * @param string $login
 */
public function setLogin($login)
{
    $this->login = $login;
}

/**
 * Get login
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getLogin()
{
    return $this->login;
}

/**
 * Set pass
 *
 * @param string $pass
 */
public function setPass($pass)
{
    $this->pass = $pass;
}

/**
 * Get pass
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPass()
{
    return $this->pass;
}

/**
 * Add categorie
 *
 * @param Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie $categorie
 */
public function addCategorie(\Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie $categorie)
{
    $this->categorie[] = $categorie;
}

/**
 * Get categorie
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getCategorie()
{
    return $this->categorie;
}
```

}

Categorie.php:

```
namespace Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


  /**
     * Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie
     *
 * @ORM\Table(name="categorie")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Categorie
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $nomcat
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nomCat", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nomcat;

    /**
     * @var string $photo
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $photo;

    /**
     * @var $evenement
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Evenement", mappedBy="categorie")
     */
     private $evenement;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="categorie")
     */
    private $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nomcat
     *
     * @param string $nomcat
     */
    public function setNomcat($nomcat)
    {
        $this->nomcat = $nomcat;
    }

    /**
     * Get nomcat
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNomcat()
    {
        return $this->nomcat;
    }

    /**
     * Set photo
     *
     * @param string $photo
     */
    public function setPhoto($photo)
    {
        $this->photo = $photo;
    }

    /**
     * Get photo
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhoto()
    {
        return $this->photo;
    }

    /**
     * Add user
     *
     * @param Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\User $user
     */
    public function addUser(\Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->user[] = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Add evenement
     *
     * @param Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie $evenement
     */
    public function addEvenement(\Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Evenement $evenement)
    {
        $this->evenement[] = $evenement;
    }

    /**
     * Get evenement
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getEvenement()
    {
        return $this->evenement;
    }
}
```

Evenement.php

```
<?php

namespace Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;



/**
 * Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Evenement
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="evenement")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Evenement
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $nom
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var datetime $date
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string $description
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=400, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var integer $ticket
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Ticket", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $ticket;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="evenement")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var Categorie
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categorie", inversedBy="evenement")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categorie_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $categorie;

    /**
     * @var Lieu
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Lieu")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lieu_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $lieu;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param datetime $date
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return datetime 
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set ticket
     *
     * @param integer $ticket
     */
    public function setTicket($ticket)
    {
        $this->ticket = $ticket;
    }

    /**
     * Get ticket
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getTicket()
    {
        return $this->ticket;
    }

    /**
     * Add user
     *
     * @param Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\User $user
     */
    public function addUser(\Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->user[] = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set categorie
     *
     * @param Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie $categorie
     */
    public function setCategorie(\Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie $categorie)
    {
        $this->categorie = $categorie;
    }

    /**
     * Get categorie
     *
     * @return Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie 
     */
    public function getCategorie()
    {
        return $this->categorie;
    }

    /**
     * Set lieu
     *
     * @param Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Lieu $lieu
     */
    public function setLieu(\Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Lieu $lieu)
    {
        $this->lieu = $lieu;
    }

    /**
     * Get lieu
     *
     * @return Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Lieu 
     */
    public function getLieu()
    {
        return $this->lieu;
    }




    public function getCategorieId(\Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie $categorie)
    {
        $idc= $categorie->getId();
        return $idc;
    }

     }
```

Now the action in my controller that would allow me to display events(evenements) after getting the user's id and the category he's interessted in is(the argument $id is the user's id):

```
 public function interetAction($id)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $users = $em->getRepository('Mql14mqlmeBundle:User')->find($id);
    foreach($users->getCategorie() as $cat) {

    $events=$cat->getEvenement();

}


return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('Mql14mqlmeBundle:Event:interet.html.twig', array(

        'categoriesEvents' => $events,
));

    }
```

But with this action even if the user is intressted in many categories, the events that are displayed are of only one categories, so what should I do to be able to dispaly all the events of all the categories that a certain user is intressted in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your controller at line: 
`$events=$cat->getEvenement();`
change it to:
`$events[]=$cat->getEvenement();`

beacause in foreach loop you override $events variable each time.

Comment: I added the [], but now I'm geetin a problem accessing the name of the event, in the twig the code is as follow:{% for c in categoriesEvents %}
{{ c.nom}}
{% endfor %}. and the error I'm getting is "Method "nom" for object "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" does not exist in Mql14mqlmeBundle:Event:interet.html.twig at line 3 ". nom is an attribute of the Evenement, and it works in other twigs

Comment: oops! create query like this: $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
                'SELECT e  FROM mqlmeBundle:Evenement e'
                . ' JOIN e.categorie c '
                . ' JOIN c.user u '
                . ' WHERE u.id=:userId'
                . ' ')
                ->setParameter('userId', $userId);
        
        $events = $query->getResult();

Comment: if in controller use $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQuery( 'SELECT e FROM ...  ;-)

Comment: I got the error  Call to undefined method Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry::getManager() so isntead I put $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->createQuery..., but still i geet an error :Unknown Entity namespace alias 'mqlmeBundle'

Comment: change it to Mql14mqlmeBundle:Evenement m must become M

Comment: I tried that also and I get this error "Invalid parameter: token userId is not defined in the query. " I also changed the query that you gave me to this :$query = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->createQuery( 'SELECT e FROM Mql14mqlmeBundle:Evenement e' . ' JOIN e.categorie c ' . ' JOIN c.user u ' . ' WHERE u.id=:id' . ' ') 
     ->setParameter('userId', $id); since I'm working with the id in the action's parameter, I hope that's correct right?

Comment: I changed userId to id and it work perfectly now thank you very much  mohsenkw